# Change date format for news pages (Site pages)

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to change the date format for my site which I do via --> regional settings --> Locale to the country with the date format I want. When I look at the page library I get the correct date:

[image]

However, when I go to the news articles/site pages the date is wrong and have not changed:

[image]

I have tried to reindex the site page library without results. Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is a known issue with modern pages.
See [this](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/31505407-publish-date-format-defaulting-to-us-format-in-mod) UserVoice.
In short: It should have been fixed but users are claiming that the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, when I use the modern experience and try to change the region in regional settings --> Locale, the time format of the site page library does change accordingly, but the published time in pages does not change, and so are the modified date. The only difference in my end is that the date itself is correct.

I also tried to modify the settings in Admin-center>Update your profile>Region settings but it didn't work.
So I would suggest that you open a service request for more help.